# Trouble generating libgdx project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx

I'm trying to generate a project using libgdx in eclipse. I'm operating on a Crunchbang distribution of Linux, and using a jdk7 version of Java. No matter what i do to try and please the gdx-setup.jar, i receive this error.

I end up with:

"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file '/home/toastacer01/workspace/build.gradle' line: 64
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'workspace'.

  > com/github/jtakakura/gradle/plugins/robovm/RoboVMPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 45.379 secs
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> General -> Exisiting Projects into Workspace
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> YourProject.ipr"

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: UPDATE: I had unchecked the "IOS" and "HTML" subproject options -which appeared to be selected by Default- and the build was successful. This seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check it if you have the correct Java version, bigger than the 7 update 51 (7u51)

Answer (score 1):

Check your jdk 64-bit or 32-bit? Check your Eclipse also 64 or 32 bits? Make sure both of them (jdk and Eclipse) should be same version.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have solved it. 
Go to Eclipse.app/Contents/info.plist. add this

```
<key>Eclipse</key>
    <array>
      <key>JVMVersion</key>
      <string>1.7*</string>
    </array>
```